# Error Missing Number, treated as zero after two If

Tags: ifthenelse

I have trouble with `\tikzset`.
When I create a function (here `foo`), the parameter `\lfvert` is not recognize on the second if statement. (The node didn't print it anymore)
And that give me the following error `Missing number, treated as zero`.

Despite the error didn't break my graph, I want to compile without error and avoid some snowball effect for the futur.

I try with `{\lfvert == 0}` instead of `\lfvert == 0` but nothing change.

Can someone help me to find what it is the problem ?
Cause the indication error looks to be too generic...

Best regard.

Code :

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{ifthen}


\tikzset{
    foo/.pic={
            \tikzset{%
                /foo/.cd,
                #1
            }

            \ifthenelse{\cubenotateddd>0}{
                \node[] at (5,5) {LFVERT=\lfvert};                
                \ifthenelse{\lfvert == 0}{
                    \node[] at (5,2) {LFVERT=\lfvert};
                }{}
            }{}
        },
    %% All parameters
    /foo/.search also={/tikz},
    /foo/.cd,
    lfv/.store in=\lfvert,
    cube/.store in=\cubenotateddd,
    %% Initialisation of parameters
    lfv=2,
    cube=2,
}

\begin{document}
Hello, test variable in IF.
\newline
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.09, line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle
        45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
    \pic[] at (1cm,-3cm,0cm) {foo={lfv=2}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `=` instead of `==`; cf. https://texdoc.org/serve/ifthen.pdf/0

Comment: This is a solution, thanks for the answer!